# How do you find the sum of $\sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+i) $?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do you find the sum of $\sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+i) $ ?

Actually, I am especially confused because of of the n-1. Usually, I'd start with stuff like: 
$$\sum \limits_{i=0}^{0}(1+i) = ?$$
$$\sum \limits_{i=0}^{1}(1+i) = ?$$
$$\sum \limits_{i=0}^{2}(1+i) = ?$$

But I don't know what to do with the n-1...
Any tips is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Keep going with the pattern you have. That is,
$(1+0)+(1+1)+(1+2)+ \cdots (1+(n-1))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the index of summation: let $k=i+1$. Then as $i$ runs from $0$ to $n-1$, $k$ runs from $0+1=1$ to $(n-1)+1=n$, and you have

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+i)=\sum_{k=1}^nk\;,$$

a summation that you’ve probably already encountered.

In this simple problem you don’t actually have to do that: you can simply write out some terms and see what’s happening, as in **Jam**’s answer, but in more complicated problems it can be very helpful to understand how to make useful changes in the index of summation in order to simplify a calculation.

It can also be useful to split the summation in two:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i\;.$$

Each of these is easier to handle than the original: the first is simply the some of $n$ identical terms, so it’s $n\cdot 1=n$. The $i=0$ term in the second contributes nothing, so the second is just

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i\;,$$

which again is something that you’ve probably seen before, though perhaps not with $n-1$ in the upper limit. If you know that

$$\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}2\;,$$

however, you can simply substitute $n-1$ for $n$ to find that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i=\frac{(n-1)\big((n-1)+1\big)}2=\frac{(n-1)n}2\;.$$

Or you can observe that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i=\left(\sum_{i=1}^ni\right)-n=\frac{n(n+1)}2-n\;,$$

since only the $i=n$ term appears in the second summation but not in the first. Then you can go on and simplify the final expression.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+i)
&=(1+0)+(1+1)+(1+2)+\dots+(1+(n-1))
\\
&=1+2+3+\dots+n
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} ( 1 + i) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i$.

We have that $\sum_{i=0}^{n} i = \frac {n(n+1)}2, $, so, with $n-1$ in place of $n$, we have $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i = \frac {(n-1)((n-1)+1)}2 = \frac {(n-1)(n)}2 = \frac{n^2 -n}{2}$.

For our other sum, we have $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 + ... (n$ times) = $n$.

Then combining the sums, we arrive at $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} ( 1 + i) = \frac{n^2 -n}{2} + n = \frac{n^2 + n}2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints.**

- You can split the sum and you are left to compute: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k.$$
- The last sum can be tricky, I recommend you to define: 
  $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k.$$
  Notice that the sum you are looking for is equal to $f'(1)$ and that $f(x)=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$ (using the formula for a geometric sum).

Comment: I think the second option is a little bit overkill.

Comment: @Jam It might be indeed, I wanted to introduce to the OP this "trick". Just in case they'll encounter look alike sums.

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood your post as two options. I mean to say that the second step is a little bit overkill.